# To find sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

How do i start this? Any hints will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Hint: the sum of the coefficients is the value at $x=1$ which is $3^n$.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Ok I'm confused by this problem. If you expand this out for a positive integer power, you get each degree of $x$ from $-1$ to $-2n$, plus you have a constant term. So there will always be $2n+1$ terms in the expansion. I'm not seeing how you can ever get $28$ terms. I even checked with Wolfram for $n=13$ and $14$ and they have $27$ and $29$ terms respectively.

Comment: @Elliot: And if they mean the number of terms before like terms are collected, the number of terms must be a power of $3$. (Moreover, the available answers imply that $n$ is $5,6$, or $7$, none of which is consistent with either reading.)

Comment: After expansion you'll get a sum of terms in the form $\frac{a_k}{x^k}$ where $a_k$ is the coefficient. For $x=1$ the sum gives the sum of the coefficients.

Comment: @ElliotG There are *at most* $2 n + 1$ terms since some of them may cancel out when collected. Though, as you noted, this does not appears to be the case for this particular function. I wonder if there is maybe a typo somewhere.

Comment: Thought: The multiple choices can be written as $2^6$, $3^7$, $3^5$, and $3^6$, and based strictly on the way novice exam-writers think, the most likely answer is $3^6$ (irrespective of the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few months ago, a student brought this question to my attention. It baffled me for a while (The number of terms is given as 28. Is it before/after gathering terms with powers of x? If you gather, you only get 13 terms).

It appeared in IIT-2016-Mains entrance examination (Indian Institute of Technology). A student gets 1 or 2 minutes to answer the question.

A student is expected to use Trinomial Expansion, without gathering terms (That makes it ill-formed).

In [Trinomial Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion), the number of terms is given out as:

> (n+1)(n+2)/2=28
>   Thus n=6.
>   Th sum of coefficients is given as: $3^n=729$

Here is the [website](http://jeemain.nic.in/webinfo/Public/Home.aspx), [question paper](http://jeemain.nic.in/webinfo/PDF/03-04-2016-SetH.pdf) and [answer key](http://www.engineering.careers360.com/sites/default/files/JEE-Main-2016-Answer-Key-H.pdf)

---

**Explanation on how gathering reduces number of terms:**
There are 28 terms in the full trinomial expansion. A lot of terms can be combined, with similar powers of x.

For ex., consider the term with $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^4}$ in it. This can be obtained from the following three terms:

> $\displaystyle \binom{6}{4,0,2} \,\, (1)^4 \,\, \left(\frac{-2} {x}\right)^0 \,\,  \left(\frac{4}{x^2}\right)^2  \,\, +$ 
>   $\displaystyle \binom{6}{3,2,1} \,\,  (1)^3 \,\,  \left(\frac{-2}{x}\right)^2 \,\,  \left(\frac{4}{x^2}\right)^1  \,\, +$ 
>   $\displaystyle \binom{6}{2,4,0} \,\,  (1)^2 \,\,  \left(\frac{-2}{x}\right)^4 \,\,  \left(\frac{4}{x^2}\right)^0$ 
>   $\displaystyle = \frac{1440}{x^4}$

The above uses the notation of trinomial coefficients as follows:

> $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k_1,k_2,k_3}$ is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{n!}{k_1!\,\,k_2!\,\,k_3!}$

When you simplify all the terms, you get only 13 terms (by summarizing 28 terms):

> \begin{equation} \\
> 1 - \frac{12}{x} + \frac{84}{x^2} - \frac{400}{x^3} + \frac{1440}{x^4} - \frac{4032}{x^5} + \frac{9024}{x^6} - \frac{16128}{x^7} + \frac{23040}{x^8} - \frac{25600}{x^9} + \frac{21504}{x^{10}} - \frac{12288}{x^{11}} + \frac{4096}{x^{12}}
> \end{equation}

Comment: Good answer as it points to a most plausible mistake in the stated problem. It would be nice if you could strikingly restate the problem with the correct wording (by adding *trinomial*) and everything has been settled. (+1)

Comment: Will this formula fails when  some terms will cancel out? I have seen trinomial expansions with terms $2n+1$

Comment: @J.Deff, I don't have terms that cancel out exactly (i.e., like +2-2=0). But, terms do get summarized (i.e., like +4-2=2). That gives us 13 terms, which results in fractional value for 'n'. Thus the question makes sense only when we interpret it as _The number of terms in the trinomial expansion of .... is 28. Find the sum of the coefficients in the expansion_

Answer (score 2):

I fully agree with all concerns expressed in the previous answer and comments. Surely this question is formulated in an unclear manner. In my opinion, a possibility is that who conceived this problem did not refer to the actual coefficients  resulting by assigning to $x $ specific values, but simply to the generic binomial coefficients resulting from the expansion of an expression of the form $(a+b+c)^n $ . If we interpret the question in this way, we get that, for any given $n $, there are:

- $3$ terms containing only one variable  (i.e., $a^n $, $b^n $, and $c^n $);
- $3 (n-1)$ terms containing two  variables. This is obtained by giving, for each of the $3$ possible pairs $ab $, $ac $, $bc $, all possible exponents $i,n-i$ (with $1 \leq i \leq n-1$) to the two variables;
- $1/2 \, (n-1)(n-2)$  terms containing all three variables. This is obtained by giving, for any given exponent $j$ of the first variable (with $1 \leq j \leq n-2$), all possible $n-j-1$ exponents to the other two variables, thus leading to the sum $\sum_{j=1}^{n-2} n-j-1$, which in turn corresponds to the sum of the first $n-2$ integers.

So the total number of terms of our expansion is $$3 + 3 (n-1)+1/2 \, (n-1)(n-2 ) $$ Simplifying and equalizing it to $28$, we get $ 1/2 \, n^2+3/2 \, n+1 =28$, whose positive solution is $n=6$.

Once established the value of $n $ which gives  $28$ terms, we can directly calculate the sum of all binomial coefficients of the expansion (all considered as positive) by setting $a=b=c=1$ (or equivalently $x=-2$ in the expression reported in the OP): in fact, in this way any binomial coefficient remains unaltered in the expansion.  So we are left with $(1+1+1)^6=3^6=729$, which may potentially be the correct answer in the original interpretation of the person who conceived the problem.

This possible solution is only a hypothesis, driven by the fact that other interpretations seem to give results that are not included in the four possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

As already indicated in the comments there seems to be a typo in the stated problem.

> Let
>   \begin{align*}
>   A(x)=\left(1-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)^n=\sum_{k=-2n}^0a_kx^k\qquad\qquad\qquad n\in\mathbb{N} \tag{1}
>   \end{align*}

We assume $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Since $A(x)$ is the product of $n$ factors $\left(1-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)$ and each of them contributes to the exponent $k$ of $x^k$ either $0,-1$ or $-2$ the smallest exponent is $-2n$ while the largest is $0$. This explains the index range of the series representation in (1).

> According to the problem the sum of the coefficients of $A(x)$ is one of
>   \begin{align*}
> 64,243,729,2187\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

The sum of the coeffcients of $A(x)$ is the expression evaluated at $x=1$ and we obtain
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=-2n}^0a_k=A(1)=(1-2+4)^n=3^n
  \end{align*}

Since the result is of the form $3^n$ we can exclude $64=2^6$ leaving three candidates 
\begin{align*}
243&=3^5\\
729&=3^6\\
2187&=3^7
\end{align*} as possible solution with $n=5,6$ or $n=7$.

The index in the series expression of $A(x)$ starts from $-2n$ and ends with $0$. So, the series representation of $A(x)$ consists of at most $2n+1$ different terms.

Substituting the possible candidates $3^5,3^6$ and $3^7$ gives at most $11,13$ and $15$ different terms. In fact, Wolfram Alpha shows they contain *precisely*  $11,13$ resp. $15$ terms.

> **Conclusion:** None of the candidates has a series representation with $28$ different terms and coefficients which sum up to $3^n$. This strongly indicates the problem is not correctly specified.

Comment: Maybe some terms cancel out

Comment: @J.Deff: In fact no terms cancel out when $n=5,6$ or $n=7$ as WA shows (see paragraph before conclusion). Since $A(1)=3^n$ there are no other plausible candidates other than $3^n$. Do you agree?